# Can this plant be identified even though its dead and all dried up?

Tags: identification

Here are a few photos. 
[image][image][image][image]
The thing is loaded with thousands of small black seeds. Right now, It's in an empty pot. It was originally planted outside a friend's house. I wanted cuttings but couldnt break even a single piece off cause the wood on it is extremely hard even though it's dead. Almost very rubber like despite being so thin. Thats when the friend pulled out the pruners and cut the whole thing off. It had dried up anyway. Other then that, i remember it having an upright habit and a very smooth and glossy appearance with bright dark green foliage. Very needle like but surprisingly super soft to the touch. If i had to make a comparison, I'd say that it looked very similar to a foxtail fern in terms of colour and texture but much bigger and more compact.

Comment: You may revive it by watering. Some plants from dry climates do it. [But i'm not sure about this plant]. I'm not an expert from plant on hot climate, so i cannot help further.

Comment: You could collect the seeds, plant some, do an ID then?

Comment: Cut off a small sprig, and over a sheet of paper rub the sprig between your palms to get the dried foliage to fall onto the paper. Transfer the powder to an envelope, take it to your local market and seek out a herb person - get them to see if they recognize the characteristic odour of the powder if it has one.